# Replace search icon in react-native-paper searchbar with icons from MaterialCommunityIcons

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I want to change the search icon in the [searchbar](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/searchbar.html) of react-native-paper with the barcode-scan icon.
The native-paper uses [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) for icons and barcode-scan available in [MaterialCommunityIcons](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/barcode-scan)
Here is the code that I tried which gives a blank instead of an icon

```
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
<Searchbar
  placeholder="Search"
  onChangeText={query => { this.setState({ firstQuery: query }); }}
  value={firstQuery}
  icon={<MaterialCommunityIcon name="barcode-scan" size={30}/>}
/>
```

Is this the right way or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the callback to pass component in icon prop

```
icon={() => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="barcode-scan" size={30}/>}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Why this isn't anywhere in the docs is beyond me.

Comment: I tried it and the icon is showing outside the search input. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding '()=>' in icon wiil be suffice

```js
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
<Searchbar
  placeholder="Search"
  onChangeText={query => { this.setState({ firstQuery: query }); }}
  value={firstQuery}
  icon={()=><MaterialCommunityIcon name="barcode-scan" size={30}/>}
/>
```